# How can I make it? (Shadows CSS3)

Tags: css, shadows

[image]

I don't even mind how I can create it. Any ideas?

Comment: It would be better to use photoshop.

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. You have to of put some effort into what you're trying to do and then bring reasonable problems to the forum if you can't figure it out. Protip : shadows like this are probably best done with an image.

Comment: thanx guys. i just study CSS3 and found interesting shadows pic :)
Sorry

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp ... +1 to what Bosworth99 said - first search then ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below code for the shadow effect. better you use css than images for shadows effects. because css is easy to create,edit and load fastly. images are not easy to create,edit and to load fastly compared with the css.

```
    <div class="box effect2">
        <h3>Effect 2</h3>
    </div>


    .box h3{
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
}
.box {
    width:70%;
    height:200px;
    background:#FFF;
    margin:40px auto;
}

/*==================================================
 * Effect 2
 * ===============================================*/
.effect2
{
  position: relative;
}
.effect2:before, .effect2:after
{
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
.effect2:after
{
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

[Reference Link](https://paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects)